# psycopg2 Postgres COPY EXPERT to Pandas read_csv using memory buffer fails with ValueError

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm running the following code using the psycopg2 driver in Python 3.5 to Pandas 19.x.

```
 buf = io.StringIO()
 cursor = conn.cursor()
 sql_query = 'COPY ('+ base_sql + ' limit 100) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER'
 cursor.copy_expert(sql_query, buf)
 df = pd.read_csv(buf.getvalue(),engine='c')
 buf.close()
```

The **read_csv** blows chunks when reading from the memory buffer:

```
pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:4175)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\parser.c:8333)()

C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py in exists(path)
     17     """Test whether a path exists.  Returns False for broken symbolic links"""
     18     try:
---> 19         os.stat(path)
     20     except OSError:
     21         return False

ValueError: stat: path too long for Windows
```

Uh..wot path? buf is in memory. What am I missing here?

Just FYI, the Copy to seems to be working as expected.

**SOLUTION CODE BELOW**

Thanks to the answer below, My query speed doubled using this method and my memory use dropped by 500%. Here is my final test code included to help others resolve their performance issues. I'd love to see any code that improves this! Be sure to link back to this question in your question.

```
# COPY TO CSV quick and dirty performance test
import io
import sys

start = time.time()
conn_str_copy= r'postgresql+psycopg2://' + user_id + r":" + pswd + r"@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:ppppp/my_database"
result = urlparse(conn_str_copy)
username = result.username
password = result.password
database = result.path[1:]
hostname = result.hostname

size = 2**30
buf = io.BytesIO()
# buf = io.StringIO()

engine = create_engine(conn_str_copy)
conn_copy= psycopg2.connect(
    database=database, user=username, password=password, host=hostname)

cursor_copy = conn_copy.cursor()
sql_query = 'COPY ('+ my_sql_query + ' ) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER'
cursor_copy.copy_expert(sql_query,  buf, size)
print('time:', (time.time() - start)/60, 'minutes or ', time.time() - start, 'seconds')
tmp = buf.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(buf,engine='c', low_memory=False )
buf.close()
print('time:', (time.time() - start)/60, 'minutes or ', time.time() - start, 'seconds')
```

Speed is ~4 minutes to copy the data from postgres and less than 30 seconds to load it into the the pandas dataframe. Note the copy command is a feature of the psycopg2 driver and may not work in other drivers.

Comment: try removing `.getvalue()` so just `df = pd.read_csv(buf,engine='c')`  Not certain, just guessing

Comment: @piRSquared: you're right. You have to pass a file handle, and passing `getvalue()` makes pandas believe you're passing a filename.

Comment: but there's more to it: you have to "rewind" the buffer object as well or it won't work.

Comment: And that's why the world needs code review! Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a file handle or a filename to `pandas.read_csv()`.

Passing `buf.getvalue()` makes pandas `read_csv` believe you're passing a filename since object doesn't have a `read` method, except that the "filename" is the buffer and it's seen as too long (windows limits to 255 characters for filenames)

You almost got it. Since `buf` is already a file-like object, just pass it as-is. Small detail: you have to rewind it because previous `cursor.copy_expert(sql_query, buf)` call probably used `write` and `buf` position is at the end (try without it, you'll probably get an empty dataframe)

```
buf.seek(0)  # rewind because you're at the end of the buffer
df = pd.read_csv(buf,engine='c')
```